# List comprehension - attempting to create dictionary from array of key-value pair arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

While trying to create a dict using list comprehension (without overwriting generated list keys)

```
x = {}
entries = [[1,'1a'], [2,'2a'], [3,'3a'], ['1', '1b'], ['2', '2b'], ['3', '3b']]
discardable = [x.setdefault(entry[0], []).append(entry[1]) for entry in entries]

Error: name 'x' is not defined
```

I was expecting x to be populated as:

```
{1: ['1a', '1b'], 2: ['2a', '2b'], 3: ['3a', '3b']}
```

How to explain this / make this work?
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The code you provided works for me, but the result is not what you want: `{1: ['1a'], 2: ['2a'], 3: ['3a'], '1': ['1b'], '2': ['2b'], '3': ['3b']}`

Comment: Your code works for me too. The result is `{1: ['1a'], 2: ['2a'], 3: ['3a'], '1': ['1b'], '2': ['2b'], '3': ['3b']}`

Comment: It makes no sense to use a list comprehension here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the keys are `str` and some are `int`, so this will produce

```
{'1': ['1a', '1b'], 2: ['2a'], 3: ['3a'], '2': ['2b'], '3': ['3b']}
```

You need to cast `entry[0]` to `int`

```
x = {}
entries = [[1,'1a'], [2,'2a'], [3,'3a'], ['1', '1b'], ['2', '2b'], ['3', '3b']]
[x.setdefault(int(entry[0]), []).append(entry[1]) for entry in entries]
```

`print(x)` will give

```
{1: ['1a', '1b'], 2: ['2a', '2b'], 3: ['3a', '3b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
entries = [['1','1a'], [2,'2a'], [3,'3a'], ['1', '1b'], ['2', '2b'], ['3', '3b']]
x = defaultdict(list)
[x[a].append(b) for a,b in entries]
x = dict(x)
```

---

**Output**

```
{'1': ['1a', '1b'], 2: ['2a'], 3: ['3a'], '2': ['2b'], '3': ['3b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to merge the value of (1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'). The code you provided works, but it doesn't handle the type between `int` and `str`. All you need to do is cast `str` into `int` so the value would be merged.

Try this:

```
x = {}
entries = [[1,'1a'], [2,'2a'], [3,'3a'], ['1', '1b'], ['2', '2b'], ['3', '3b']]
discardable = [x.setdefault(int(entry[0]), []).append(entry[1]) for entry in entries]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to explain this / make this work?

A comprehension creates one output for each input, and they're not intended for mutation

> Is there any other way to achieve this?

Use a normal procedural loop. Or use a multidict but the standard library doesn't provide one.

You could perform functional transformations until you get the proper "shape" (using `sorted`, `itertools.groupby` and some more mapping) but I don't think that'd be worth it, a bog-standard `for` loop would be much more readable:

```py
for k, v in entries:
    x.setdefault(int(x), []).append(v)
```

versus:

```py
x = {
    x: list(v[1] for v in vs)
    for x, vs in itertools.groupby(
        sorted((int(k), v) for k, v in entries),
        lambda it: it[0]
    )
}
```

the comprehension is less readable and less efficient

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). they work much like list comprehensions

```
entries = [[1,'1a'], [2,'2a'], [3,'3a'], ['1', '1b'], ['2', '2b'], ['3', '3b']]

# Build a dictionary from the values in entries
discardable = {key:val for key, val in entries}

print (discardable)
# Result: {1: '1a', 2: '2a', 3: '3a', '1': '1b', '2': '2b', '3': '3b'}
```